# Getting a file without saving it aiohttp discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, aiohttp

So i have a command where it sends whatever the user said after the command to a website api and sends the file the site generates. However i'm changing over to aiohttp as it doesn't block like the standered requests functions

This is how i do it with normal requests and it works fine:

```
      elif (data[0].lower() == ">signgirl"):
        await bot.send_typing(message.channel)

        tmp = message.content.replace(">signgirl", "")

        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(tmp.encode('utf-8'))

        print(tmp, m.hexdigest())
        r = requests.post("http://localhost/sign.php", stream=True, data={'text': tmp})
        if (r.status_code() == 200):
            await bot.send_file(destination=message.channel, filename=str(m.hexdigest()+".png"), fp=r.raw)
```

However when i try with aiohttp i have no idea how to actually get the raw file data..
So i made this function to get it. but it doesn't let me return an image and i cannot check the http status code without it causing an error.

```
async def post_data2(url, payload):
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session2:
    async with session2.post(url, data=payload) as response2:
        output = {}
        output['data'] = await Image.open(BytesIO(response2.read()))
        output['status'] = 200 #await str(response2.status()) #Why is this object not callable?
        return output
```

How else could i do this? Is this possible? aiohttp doesn't seem as easy to understand.

Comment: Why are you awaiting everything? Only coroutines can be awaited, str and Image (from pillow?) are **not** coroutines.

Comment: It's actually so that i can await the response2.read(),i must have put it at the start to shut the thing up about me not awaiting. It's really not the best thing to do i'm also new to python but not to coding in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mister Day "V" Own from the discord.py discord server sent a perfect example of getting and sending the data

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    # or use a session you already have
    async with session.get("http://example.com") as resp:
        buffer = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
        # buffer is a file-like

await client.send_file(channel, fp=buffer, filename="whatever")
```